# Calculate sample mean confidence interval of noisy logistical distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, mean, logistic-distribution

I have $n$ samples which follow a logistic distribution with unknown $u$ and $s$; it is affected by a Gaussian noise with 0 mean.
I would like to estimate its average $u$ with a confidence interval (let's say 95%).

I did compute the data set average $x$, and the data-set variance $v$.
As Wikipedia says, I should do [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/953450702f09946ea8f70bc38628be8e3a39f6ae)... I am confused on how to get the correct parameters in $t$, if $t$ is a t-student distribution.

I found a shady example which is supposed to have a 95% confidence interval

```
x <- c(0.39, 0.68, 0.82, 1.35, 1.38, 1.62, 1.70, 1.71, 1.85, 2.14, 2.89, 3.69)
s2 <- var(x)
mx <- mean(x)
n <- length(x)
a <- qt(0.975, df = n - 1) * sqrt(s2 / n)
l.inf <- mx – a
l.sup <- mx + a
cat("(",l.inf,":",l.sup,")\n")
```

[qt generates a t-student distribution in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/TDist.html)

**Will it work on my data?**
Should I calculate the Phi over the Gaussian tables? because I do not recognize that shady 0.975 (95%) or 0.995 (99%) of the example, is it $1-((1-0.99)/2)$ ?

Comment: You have data from a logistic distribution, you say, but contaminated with gaussian noise. That makes for data from a logistic-normal convolution.  I see no use of this assumption in your presented calculations, which seems to calculate a t interval, as if the data was normal. Can you clarify?